# openssl build error while trying to run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rubygems, bundler

I'm new to Ruby, so just trying to find my way. I am trying to run bundle install on a gemfile which has dependency on openssl. But I get the error - "An Error occurred while installing OpenSSL 2.2.0 , and Bundler cannot continue". When I open mkmf.log, I see: "conftest.c In function 't': conftest.c:13:57: error: 't_open' undeclared (first used in this function)"
I have already run the following command:

```
sudo bundle config build.openssl --with-openssl-dir=/home/arnab/openssl1/openssl-1.1.1l
```

openssl-1.1.1l is the folder where I have unzipped the contents of openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz available on openssl downloads website.
Any help is much appreciated. I'm using Ruby 2.5.8, Bundler 2.2.31.
Also, before the build failed, it showed some things missing:

```
checking for t_open() in -lnsl ...no
checking for socket() in -lsocket ...no
checking for openssl/ssl.h ...no
checking for openssl/ssl.h ...no

OS: Ubuntu 16
```

Comment: Try installing openssl with Homebrew first

Comment: It's ubuntu, and I have already tried sudo apt-get install openssl

Comment: Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv` ?

Comment: I am using rvm manager

Comment: The gem you're trying to install has a dependency on OpenSSL 2.2.0 - thats not going to work with 1.1.1.

Comment: I would also really recommend Linuxbrew on Ubunto as a compliment for `apt-get`. It installs packages in your user directory which removes the need for sudo. Downloading zip/tarballs manually is almost never the right answer to any question.